# Grouping of robot keywords called from a Python keyword

Tags: python, continuous-integration, automated-tests, robotframework

When using robotframework, the call sequence of keywords is nicely grouped in the output logs. For eg If a robot keyword "startup" calls robot keywords "make connection", "start server" etc, the output log shows a '+' sign over startup and on expanding shows keywords 'make connection' and 'start server'. However, this grouping breaks if I write "startup" in python instead of robotframework language. In fact "startup" does not appear in the logs at all.This makes it difficult to troubleshoot issues. Is there anyway to make the grouping work when robot keywords are called from a python keyword/function?
Thanks